# ProcessBuilder is not called when trying to start a process

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, javacv

I am trying to understand more about the ffmpeg usage in JavaCV for android studio and for said task I am trying to use ProcessBuilder. I tried writting a simple program to debug the `pb.start();` Although, I am not getting a response. What I did was to start a default/empty activity and pasted the following program:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int cols = 192;
    static final int rows = 108;
    static final String ffmpeg = Loader.load(org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.ffmpeg.class);
    static final String rtmp_url = "test.flv";
    static final String[] command = {ffmpeg,
            "-y",
            "-f", "rawvideo",
            "-vcodec", "rawvideo",
            "-pix_fmt", "bgr24",
            "-s", (Integer.toString(cols) + "x" + Integer.toString(rows)),
            "-r", "10",
            "-i", "pipe:",
            "-c:v", "libx264",
            "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
            "-preset", "ultrafast",
            "-f", "flv",
            rtmp_url};
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Thread(t1).start();

    }
    private static Runnable t1 = () -> {
        Log.e("TAG", "void OnCreate called successfully!");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command).redirectErrorStream(true);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        try {
            Process process = pb.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            OutputStream writer = process.getOutputStream();
            Log.e("TAG", "Something good happened here");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TAG", "Nothing good happened here");
        }
    };


}
```

My current problem is that I can't seem to start properly the processBuilder process via pb.start();

I get the following logs from the logcat panel:

```
2022-06-14 17:24:46.328 13371-13371/com.example.myapplication E/TAG: void OnCreate called successfully!
2022-06-14 17:24:46.333 13371-13371/com.example.myapplication E/TAG: Nothing good happened here
```

I'd like to understand why is it skipping the try/catch block and not starting the process?

EDIT: I made some changes as per @g00se's suggestions and I got the following stack trace from the code above:

```
2022-06-15 00:32:26.700 29787-29787/? E/USNET: USNET: appName: com.example.myapplication
2022-06-15 00:32:29.328 29787-29828/com.example.myapplication E/TAG: void OnCreate called successfully!
2022-06-15 00:32:29.330 29787-29828/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 29787
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.lambda$static$0(MainActivity.java:48)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

Comment: I don't do Android but a. you need to do that in a separate thread and b. you need to handle the process output stream

Comment: `pb.start` goes to a thread then? how is output stream supposed to be handled in this case?

Comment: You need to read the output stream or the process can just lock up

Comment: Your logcat panel shows the message "Nothing good happened here" and therefore it seems that `pb.start()` throws an `IOException`. Unfortunately you are throwing away the `IOException`. Replace `Log.e("TAG", "Nothing good happened here");` with `Log.e("TAG", "Nothing good happened here", e);` and remove the `e.printStackTrace();` so that you can see the exception.

Comment: I removed `e.printStackTrace();` and did `Log.e("TAG", ":",e);` and it gave me the same error that I recently updated the question with: `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 25934
    java.lang.NullPointerException`. At the line `pb.start():`

Comment: That `NullPointerException` in the stacktrace is already helpful. The documentation for [`ProcessBuilder.start()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ProcessBuilder#start()) says that it _throws a `NullPointerException` if an element of the command list is null_. About the only thing in your command list that can be `null` is the `ffmpeg` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread isn't necessary, nor reading the output to start a process, in this case `errCode = process.waitFor();` did the trick.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader;
import org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int cols = 192;
    static final int rows = 108;
    static final String ffmpeg = Loader.load(org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.ffmpeg.class);
    static final String rtmp_url = "test.flv";
    static final String[] command = {ffmpeg,
            "-y",
            "-f", "rawvideo",
            "-vcodec", "rawvideo",
            "-pix_fmt", "bgr24",
            "-s", (Integer.toString(cols) + "x" + Integer.toString(rows)),
            "-r", "10",
            "-i", "pipe:",
            "-c:v", "libx264",
            "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
            "-preset", "ultrafast",
            "-f", "flv",
            rtmp_url};
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //new Thread(t1).start();
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("echo", "Hello World!");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        System.out.println("Run echo command");
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int errCode = 0;
        try {
            errCode = process.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Echo command executed, any errors? " + (errCode == 0 ? "No" : "Yes"));
        try {
            System.out.println("Echo Output:\n" + output(process.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            OutputStream writer = process.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("TAG", "void OnCreate called successfully!");

    }

    private static String output(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
}
```